# Code placement for launch time improvement

Tags: ios

When checking through the time profiler, there is a gap in between `Launching` and `Foreground - Active`. I assume this to be the post main time that the app takes to launch.

So, I moved functions that do not need to be triggered until launch from my `AppDelegate` to the `viewWillAppear` of the `rootViewController` of my app. And still, this code contributes to the post main time of the app.

Where should I place such code so that it doesn't affect the post main time of my app?

Comment: It depends on the code. You can further profile the app and see exactly what is delaying the launch. If something can be lazily loaded or can be done asynchronously, do it so.

Comment: I was able to figure out what exactly delays the launch. It's mostly watchers that I initialise for analytics or other services which i need initialised at the start of the app. I'm not sure if lazy loading them is advisable. Will I be able to move them elsewhere?

Comment: If you _really_ need them initialized at the start of the app (for crash reporting, theming, event logging etc) then, by definition, no. What Apple suggested (and still does for a lot of their apps) is to minimize _perceived_ launch time by registering an 'empty' first-screen screenshot (that matches the real one) as a splash screen. [Here is an article](https://techblog.izotope.com/2018/03/08/improving-your-ios-apps-launch-time/) that may also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving those initializations from `viewWillAppear` to `viewDidLoad`.  That way, they won't start up until the initial view is visible.

Comment: Tried switching between willAppear, didLoad and didAppear. All three give the same results

Comment: viewDidLoad gets called before viewWillAppear. More precisely, viewDidLoad gets called after loadView finishes, which gets called to lazy-load the view the first time the viewController.view is accessed.